# PHP: Enchant Spell Checking not working. Configuration in Windows?

Tags: php

I am attempting to get a PHP spell checking app working, however when I try and use the Enchant extension, I can't get it to check a word for spelling errors.

Web server config

- PHP version 5.4.7
- Windows Server 2008
- IIS 7

In the php.ini file I have enabled the Enchant extension. eg:

```
extension=php_enchant.dll
```

**Sample code**:

```
    $broker = enchant_broker_init();
    $tag = 'en_US';

    $bprovides = enchant_broker_describe($broker);
    echo "Current broker provides the following backend(s):\n";
    print_r($bprovides);

    $dicts = enchant_broker_list_dicts($broker);
    echo "Current broker provides the following dictionaries:\n";
    print_r($dicts);

    enchant_broker_set_dict_path($broker, ENCHANT_MYSPELL, 'C:\php5.4.7\lib\enchant\MySpell');

    if (enchant_broker_dict_exists($broker, $tag)) {
     $dict = enchant_broker_request_dict($broker, $tag);
     $word = 'soong';
     $isCorrectlySpelled = enchant_dict_check($dict, $word);

     if ($isCorrectlySpelled !== true) {
      $suggestions = enchant_dict_suggest($dict, $word);

      echo nl2br(print_r($suggestions, true));
     } else {
      echo 'The word is correctly spelt!';
     }
    }

    enchant_broker_free($broker);
```

**Returns**:

```
Current broker provides the following backend(s):
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ispell
            [desc] => Ispell Provider
            [file] => C:\php5.4.7\libenchant_ispell.dll
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => myspell
            [desc] => Myspell Provider
            [file] => C:\php5.4.7\libenchant_myspell.dll
        )

)
Current broker provides the following dictionaries:
```

However, this doesn't tell me if the word "soong" is spelt correctly or not!

Comment: How did you get php_enchant.dll working on windows.  When uncomment the extension in php.ini, the php error log says "Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_enchant.dll', even though the dll exists.  It must be missing another dependency?  Dependency Walker says it's missing libenchant.dll

Comment: It was in my php folder, but that folder wasn't part of the windows system path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is quite easy to get the Enchant extension working in Windows, IIS and PHP 5.4.7!

All you need to do is create some folders, download some dictionary files and it works brilliantly!

Go to https://wiki.mozilla.org/L10n:Dictionaries and download the dictionaries that you want to spell check against.

Then create this directory structure in your PHP folder: [PHP]\share\myspell\dicts

Finally, place the *.aff and the *.dic files (eg. en_US.aff and en_US.dic) into the dicts folder and then it works!

Now the code above **returns** the dictionary information, plus the spelling suggestions!

```
Current broker provides the following backend(s):
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ispell
            [desc] => Ispell Provider
            [file] => C:\php5.4.7\libenchant_ispell.dll
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => myspell
            [desc] => Myspell Provider
            [file] => C:\php5.4.7\libenchant_myspell.dll
        )

)
Current broker provides the following dictionaries:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lang_tag] => en_GB
            [provider_name] => myspell
            [provider_desc] => Myspell Provider
            [provider_file] => C:\php5.4.7\libenchant_myspell.dll
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lang_tag] => en_US
            [provider_name] => myspell
            [provider_desc] => Myspell Provider
            [provider_file] => C:\php5.4.7\libenchant_myspell.dll
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => suing
    [1] => sung
    [2] => goons
    [3] => song
    [4] => soon
    [5] => soon g
)
```

**Credits**:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/enchant.examples.php#109925

http://my.opera.com/iwanluijks/blog/using-enchant-with-php-on-windows-part-1

Comment: The download link for the english dictionary on mozilla's page was broken.  But I was able to get them from the firefox installation directory.  The tricky part was I had to rename them from en-US to en_US.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it didn't even listed those backends!!!

You need to copy libenchant_ispell.dll and libenchant_myspell.dll to "c:\PHP\lib\enchant".

Then after downloading dictionaries and using this UNDOCUMENTED function:

```
enchant_broker_set_dict_path($broker, ENCHANT_MYSPELL, 'C:\PHP\enchant\MySpell');
```

I made it finally work!

Answer (score 2):

I had to perform a combination of steps suggested by others here and elsewhere.  I couldn't find a single place on the net that had all of these steps documented in the same place so I'm writing them here.  I'm using Windows 7 and php 5.5 installed from xamp.  Here is what I had to do:

1. Uncomment the extension=php_enchant.dll line in php.ini
2. Add the php installation directory to the windows PATH.  Otherwise php_enchant.dll won't be able to find libenchant.dll
3. Move libenchant_ispell.dll and libenchant_myspell.dll from the php installation directory to [php]/lib/enchant/ .  You'll have to create these folders.
4. Add en_US.aff and en_US.dic to [php]/share/myspell/dicts .  You'll have to create these folders too.  Those files can be found in C:\Program Files\Firefox\dictionaries under slightly different names.  But they must be renamed to en_US.aff and en_US.dic or they won't work.

After the steps and removing the call to enchant_broker_set_dict_path() in Paul's code, it worked great.

Comment: Step 3 resolved my issue with wamp on Windows 10. On Ubuntu I don't have any similar issues.

Comment: Goddamn. Why can't they just have it as a build in function? All these complicated steps, and if we miss a single step, the whole thing won't work.