# Difficulties installing php enchant on Windows

Tags: php, windows, dll, wamp, enchant

Okay, I've read the php.net docs, I've browsed numerous sites including stackoverflow for solutions and nothing has helped. So I'm asking, is there anyone who can post a definitive guide for getting enchant to work on Windows?

My set up is:

- Windows 7
- WAMP Server 2.0
- PHP 5.3.0

PHP is located in

```
C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0
```

I downloaded the php_enchant.dll from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_enchant-1.1.0-5.3-vc9-x86.zip and unzipped its contents. I did as the readme stated and

- moved php_enchant.dll into C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext (my
  extensions path)
- moved all other dll files into C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0
- added extension=php_enchant.dll to my php.ini
- restarted httpd

For dictionaries, I followed the first answer here [PHP: Enchant Spell Checking not working. Configuration in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728842/php-enchant-spell-checking-not-working-configuration-in-windows)

- I downloaded the correct dictionary zips from Mozilla
- I placed them inside of C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/share/myspell/dicts

After all of this trying to run 
    enchant_broker_init(); 
gives a fatal error. I really don't know what else to do. If anyone can give me some advice I'd really appreciate it.

Edit: Okay so my apache error log gives the following error

```js
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_enchant.dll' - The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.\r\n in Unknown on line 0 <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_enchant.dll' - The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b>[Wed Mar 05 15:28:02 2014] [notice] Child 6128: Child process is running
```

Pulling out my hair now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean WAMPServer 2.0?

That enchant was compiled with VC9, check that your PHP and Apache were also compiled with VC9, if not you need an enchant dll that was compiled with the same compiler as your Apache and PHP.

As you have PHP5.3.0 I would guess they are compiled with VC6.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I gave and started using Vagrant. Got everything working right away. I think the days of WAMP and MAMP are done.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your tip. Vagrant looks like fun, I may have a play with that soon myself.

Comment: Cool! I've written a blog article about getting it set up using PuPHPet if you're interested http://www.rohandeshpande.com/blog/getting-started-guide-vagrant-windows-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Add PHP path to Windows PATH variable and restart wampserver.

Comment: doesn't work by modifying PATH settings, but you need to do it to work with new php.